# Channel 'core' doesn't exist - Installing extension

Tags: extensions, ce-1.9.1.1

Working on magento community 1.9.1, security patch up to date.

I've tried to install an extension, but I get this error message :

```
> Checking dependencies of packages Package core/Mage_Catalog failed:
> Channel 'core' doesn't exist Installing package
> community/Package_name_version Package community/Package_name_version
> installed successfully Package installed:  community
> Package_name_version
```

I have tried the following base on what I found on the net, which is really not a lot about this issue...

```
> ./mage mage-setup
```

Then add the extension again via magento connect & Then delete /downloader/cache.cfg

This had no result.

It's not comming from the extension because it's working fine on another instance of magento. 
The extension seems to be installed, but when I try to use it under the admin panel, i get this error :

> `Error: Http code "302" returned from extension_name`

Thank you for helping